# Почему то не находит эмоции и выдает ошибку KeyError

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Здраствуйте!
Код который выдает роли по нажатии реакции.
Выдача работает нормально, но вот забирание роли почему-то работает каряво, некоторые роли забирает, а некоторым выдает ошибку `KeyError`, хотя в конфиге все правильно.

Код:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):

    channel: discord.TextChannel = self.bot.get_channel(int(config.channel))
    message = await channel.fetch_message(int(config.message))
    member: discord.Member = utils.get(message.guild.members, id = payload.user_id)

    try:
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)
        role_remove: discord.Role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id = config.ROLES[emoji])

        await member.remove_roles(role_remove)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(repr(e))
```

Ошибка:

```
2021-07-20T06:15:27.370651+00:00 app[worker.1]: Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
2021-07-20T06:15:27.371905+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-20T06:15:27.371988+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
2021-07-20T06:15:27.371989+00:00 app[worker.1]: await coro(*args, **kwargs)
2021-07-20T06:15:27.372024+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/cogs/addrole.py", line 48, in on_raw_reaction_remove
2021-07-20T06:15:27.372025+00:00 app[worker.1]: role_remove: discord.Role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id = str(config.ROLES[emoji]))
2021-07-20T06:15:27.372094+00:00 app[worker.1]: KeyError: '<:cpp:866776827762442240>'
```

Config.py:

```
import os

ROLES = {
    '<a:python:866776924147286027>': 865971770422460417 ,# python
    '<:gamedev:866780079370665994>': 865972670780801084, #gamedev
    '<a:rubby:866776968023244800>': 866780399517302805, # rubby
    '<a:cpp:866776827762442240>': 865971579573633047, #c++
    '': 865971308826198057, #3d designer
    '️': 865973110264037416, #soft dev
    '<a:csharp:866777010294226964>': 865973760530841630, #csharp
    '<a:javascript:866777189889343540>': 865971804777742346, #javascript
    '<:java:866781829495652403>': 865971859249037352, #java
    '<a:sql:866777146273038387>': 865972812714868746, #sql
    '<a:blender:866784801838989392>': 865972970644439050, #blender
    '': 865973455442673674, #3dmax
    '️': 865972226539651114, #unity
    '⚙️': 865971897044697098, #unrealungine
    '<a:php:866777065688924170>': 866773847498555422, #php
    '️': 866637025977171989, #html\css
    '️': 865971128799330324, #Верстальщик
    '️': 865971415353393162, #бекенд
    '': 865972048832233473 #arduino
}

r = [
    '️', 
    '️',
    '<:gamedev:866780079370665994>',
    '',
    '️',
    '',
    '<a:cpp:866776827762442240>',
    '<a:csharp:866777010294226964>',
    '<a:python:866776924147286027>',
    '<a:javascript:866777189889343540>',
    '<:java:866781829495652403>',
    '<a:sql:866777146273038387>',
    '<a:blender:866784801838989392>',
    '',
    '️',
    '⚙️',
    '️',
    '<a:php:866777065688924170>',
    '<a:rubby:866776968023244800>'
]

message = os.environ.get('MESSAGE')
channel = os.environ.get('CHANNEL')
```

Роли
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скрипт ищет элемент словаря с ключом `<:cpp:866776827762442240>`, его там нет. Строку с эмоджи C++:

```py
ROLES = {
    ...
    '<a:cpp:866776827762442240>': 865971579573633047, #c++
    ...
}
```

Замените на эту:

```py
ROLES = {
    ...
    '<:cpp:866776827762442240>': 865971579573633047, #c++
    ...
}
```

Comment: сделал массив для выдачи с `<a:cpp:866776827762442240>`  а для remove `<:cpp:866776827762442240>`